# Draw line with border iPhone using CGContext

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I want to draw line with border,

right now i am doing same thing twice, means first i draw line with stroke +3 and again draw line with normal stroke like 1,

so i do run loop twice for it,

is there any other way for better performance? or any anthor way to draw two line simultaniously.??

My code is

```
  if (locations && ([locations length]/16 > 1)) {       

                CGPoint point;
                polylinewidth=10;
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, polylinewidth);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

                for (int i = 0; i <= locations.length - 32; i += 32) {
                    NSAutoreleasePool *loc = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
                    coordinates.latitude = hexDecode_iPhone([locations substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 16)]);
                    coordinates.longitude = hexDecode_iPhone([locations substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i+16, 16)]);

                    point = [mapView convertCoordinate:coordinates toPointToView:self.mapView];

                    if (i == 0)
                        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                    else
                        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                    [loc drain];
                }

                CGContextStrokePath(context);

                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, polylinewidth-5);

                CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.6);

                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

                for (int i = 0; i <= locations.length - 32; i += 32) {
                    NSAutoreleasePool *loc = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
                    coordinates.latitude = hexDecode_iPhone([locations substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 16)]);
                    coordinates.longitude = hexDecode_iPhone([locations substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i+16, 16)]);

                    point = [mapView convertCoordinate:coordinates toPointToView:self.mapView];

                    if (i == 0)
                        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                    else
                        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                    [loc drain];
                }

                CGContextStrokePath(context);  
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can probably refactor the code in your `for` loop to a separate method, since it's exactly the same code in both. But, I think your method of drawing the border, then drawing the line on top, is fairly efficient.

Comment: @CraigOtis: can i do it with 1 loop, for better performance.?
or another alternative for it?